# Delay in loading the page when creating tabs using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-tabs

In my page, I have some tabs...But as per the requirement,the tabs are displayed somewhere near the middle...So,the part which is above the tabs are loaded quickly and it is taking some time to load the part which contains the tabs...

When the main page is loaded, all the pages inside the tabs are also loaded...So it is taking some time...How can I avoid this?...

My code:

```
<div class="ui-tabs" id="tabs" style="width: 97%;display:none;">
                    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
                        <li id="planDetails-tab"><a id="hrefPlanDetailsid" accesskey="p" href="#divPlanDetailsTab" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;Plan Details</a></li>
                        <li id="testPlan-tab"><a id="hrefTestPlanid" accesskey="t" href="#divTestPlanTab" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Test Plan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>                        
                        <li id="serviceArea-tab"><a href="#divServiceAreaTab" accesskey="s" class="planTabHeader">Service Area</a></li>
                        <li id="rates-tab"><a href="#divRatesTab" accesskey="r" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rates&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li id="benefits-tab"><a href="#divBenefitsTab" accesskey="b" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Benefits&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li id="network-tab"><a href="#divNetworkEcpTab" accesskey="n" class="planTabHeader">Network ECP</a></li>
                        <li id="historical-tab"><a href="#divHistoricalTab" accesskey="h" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Historical&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                        <li id="directory-tab"><a href="#divDirectoryTab" accesskey="d" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Directory&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div id="divPlanDetailsTab" style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                            <s:include value="PlanDetail.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divTestPlanTab" style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                            <s:include value="TestPlan.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="divServiceAreaTab"
                        class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                        <s:include value="PlanServiceArea.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>                  

                    <div id="divRatesTab"
                    class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                        <s:include value="Rates.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div id="divBenefitsTab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                        <s:include value="PlanBenefits.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div id="divNetworkEcpTab"
                    class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                        <s:include value="NetworkECP.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div id="divHistoricalTab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                    <fieldset>
                        <s:include value="PlanHistorical.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divDirectoryTab"
                    class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"  style="width: 100%;">
                        <fieldset>
                            <s:include value="ProviderDirectory.jsp" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

js file:

```
$(function() {
            $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
            $tabs.css('display','block');

            //Initially hide Test Plan tab
            $('ul li#testPlan-tab').hide();
            $('#hrefTestPlanid').hide();
            $tabs.tabs({
                active : function(event, ui) {
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use content loading using AJAX method : http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

In that way, you are not loading plenty of text or element which will perhaps never be displayed

Create a directory "ajax", move the code of your tabs in specific files and define tabs like this :

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li id="planDetails-tab"><a href="ajax/divPlanDetailsTab.php" id="hrefPlanDetailsid" accesskey="p" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;Plan Details</a>
    </li>
    <li id="testPlan-tab"><a href="ajax/divTestPlanTab.php" id="hrefTestPlanid" accesskey="t" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Test Plan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {

          ui.panel.html("Loading in progress...");

          ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
        });
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I have added a loading text in my example.